# Do parentheses create a non-deduced context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

[temp.deduct.type#17](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#17) specifies that

> If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type template parameter, the non-type template parameter is used in a subexpression in the function parameter list, the expression is a non-deduced context as specified above.

which means for the following declaration of `f`

```
template<int> struct S {};

template<int i> void f(S<i + 1>) {}
```

the call `f(S<42>{})` is [rejected](https://godbolt.org/z/GcdW9KeE1).

However, if the declaration of `f` is changed to

```
template<int i> void f(S<(i)>) {}
```

only Clang [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/zje75cds5) the call, with the same error as before.

So, does adding parentheses around `i` make it a non-deduced context, because `i` is a subexpression of `(i)`?

Answer (score 2):

Subexpressions are [defined relative to immediate subexpressions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic#intro.execution-4):

> A subexpression of an expression E is an immediate subexpression of E or a subexpression of an immediate subexpression of E.

And immediate subexpressions are [defined in part as](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic#intro.execution-3):

> The immediate subexpressions of an expression E are
>
> - the constituent expressions of E's operands ([expr.prop]),

There are more possibilities, but they obviously don't apply to the case of `(N)`. So the question is whether `N` is an operand of the parenthesis expression.

Well, not according to [[expr.prim.paren]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.paren):

> A parenthesized expression (E) is a primary expression whose type, value, and value category are identical to those of E. **The parenthesized expression can be used in exactly the same contexts as those where E can be used, and with the same meaning, except as otherwise indicated.**

Emphasis added. It seems clear that in `(N)`, `N` is not an operand, so it is not an immediate subexpression, and therefore `N` is not a subexpression.

Since there is nothing in [temp.deduct.type]/17 that "indicates otherwise", it seems clear that `(N)` and `N` can be used identically.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. It seems to be a clang bug then.

Comment: Hmm, looking to see if there's a bug report against Clang, I found [this comment](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44123#c3), the first sentence of which indicates that the parentheses do matter.

Comment: @cigien: They can indicate whatever they like, but they didn't point to where the standard says `N` is a subexpression of `(N)`, and I pointed to all of the places where it definitely **isn't** said.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll wait to see if there *is* some place where it says that `()` matter.

Comment: @cigien: It matters a *lot* in `decltype`.

Comment: Right, I meant in a way that affects whether it's a deduced context. There doesn't seem to be anything in the entire clause on templates, so probably not.